# Create backup of MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating forum using PHP / MySQL. A function I am adding to it is to be able to delete Categories and I was wondering the best way to backup the topics & replies inside the category being deleted.

I know of way to do it but I have a feeling it's not the proper way of doing it, so I am looking for other options.

I have tried searching for ways other people do it but I haven't come up with any results.

Thank you.

Comment: mysqldump / event_scheduler / triggers <- Any combinations of these.

Comment: what is your way you know of?

Comment: @redreggae The way I did it about 8 years ago when I made a forum was to insert the data in a topics_backup table then delete them from the `topics` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions:

- create a post_active field defaulting to true. if the row is active, show it, if not consider it deleted
- create a duplicate table of deleted stuff. Every time you delete a row, add to the log

if you want, you can implement a version history feature by storing the data into 2 tables - one containing the hierarchy of data [table a], the other the actual information [table b]. each time an entry is modified, create a duplicate row in table B with the new data, and update the hierarchy in table A to link to the new record in table B. If the new record has a field linking to the old record, you can implement an undo feature

Comment: That's interesting. I'll have to think how I can get that version history to work for me. My tables are mostly setup for it already.

Answer (score 3):

While it may require rewriting some queries, the preferred approach is to add e.g. a `post_deleted` column and only display posts that where `post_deleted=0` on the live site.  Instead of actually *deleting* a post, set `post_deleted=1` and review it later.  You can then periodically really delete these posts if needed.  The end result is a very detailed audit trail.

Comment: Ah, yeah, didn't even think of that. That's smart.